# Generating dynamic inventory file using json file or executable without --list

Tags: ansible

I am trying to generate a dynamic inventory file. I wrote a program that generates json as well. I want to be able to call my program without a --list option or with another option (can the --list be overwritten somewhere?). If that isnt possible, is there an option to generate an inventory file (without an executable with a --list option) by just using a JSON file? That is the idea would be

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i test.json
```

where the json file is the inventory for the playbook. Right now when i try this method I receive the following error:

```
ERROR! ERROR! host range must be begin:end or begin:end:step
```

THis is the json Im working with

```
{  
   "myname":{  
      "hosts":[  
         "host1.company.biz",
         "host2.company.biz",
         "host3.company.biz",
         "host4.company.biz"
      ],
      "vars":{  
         "ansible_ssh_private_key_file":"/home/keys/.ssh/id_dev",
         "ansible_ssh_private_key_file":"/home/keys/.ssh/id_staging",
         "ansible_ssh_private_key_file":"/home/keys/.ssh/id_staging_uk"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on how to load the json directly, but I know a work around using python. If you have this pre-generated json file. You can write a simple python script that you can call with ansible-playbook. Lets call the python file test.py and the json test.json.

Here is my sample playbook..

```
---
- name: run command on on host4
  hosts: 'host4.company.biz'
  vars:
     foo: "{{ lookup('file', 'tmp.txt')  }}"
  tasks:
     - debug: var=foo
```

Here is the sample python dynamic inventory script... (Make sure to chmod +x on the python script)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from json import dumps, loads
test_file = loads(open('test.json', 'r').read())
print dumps(test_file, indent=4)

ansible-playbook -i test.py -u host4.company.biz -vvvv test.yml --connection=local.
```

Example output..

```
ok: [host4.company.biz]

TASK [debug]
*******************************************************************
task path: /home/linuxdynasty/test.yml:7
File lookup using /home/linuxdynasty/tmp.txt as file
ok: [host4.company.biz] => {
"foo": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
]
```

}

I tested this using ansible 2.0.1